# [Vue warn]: The data property “x” is already declared as a prop. BootstrapVue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

Could someone kindly advise me what I am doing wrong here?
I am using BootstrapVue to create radio buttons, in second image. In spite of I even didn't declare “checked” prop, still getting the error, in first image, for every buttons and also every form-groups in the project.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-group
      label-cols="auto"
      label="Peer Groups:"
      class="pg-button-group"
      label-class="text-primary"
      label-size="sm"
      v-if="peerGroups"
    >
      <b-form-radio-group
        v-model="selectedPg"
        :options="peerGroups"
        button-variant="primary"
        @change="pgSelectedByClick"
        buttons
        size="sm"
        class=""
      >
      </b-form-radio-group>
    </b-form-group>
  </div>
</template>
```

The Error I got:
[image: The Error I got]

Buttons which I try to create:
[image: Buttons which I try to create]

Comment: Seems like the error is in `BFormRadio` which is one level above the code you just presented.

Comment: Thanks @ssc-hrep3 I have added relevant lines too, but I don't have any other Component above with name "BFormRadio" That's why I am confused about it. Can you help me out?

Comment: But where is your `BFormRadio` component? Should this not be within the group?

Comment: Where is the <script> block?

Comment: Hi @ssc-hrep3 `BFormRadio` is a auto generated componet which is generated inside of the `BFormRadioGroup` according to it's `:options` attribute. It's handled by BootstrapVue. That's why I am not able to see the reason of error. I would like get a hit about the usage of `BFormRadioGroup` which probably causes the error. @Igor Popow is `<script> related to this issue? I can add it too, but didn't see any reason for that. Do u have an idea about it?

Comment: You can check your main.js and if you have any variable that has name 'checked' you can change. Probably in mixin.

Comment: There you go! Thanks for advicing @KaanYesil I have just figured out that I have a variable in main.js and it causes all theese errors. So that there is nothing to change on bootstrap components. Many thanks!